# Limit directories in TFileOpenDialog

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I'm using a TFileOpenDialog on a data entry form in Delphi XE. The user selects a PDF document in the dialog and the UNC path and filename gets stored in a database field. I want to limit the scope of where the user browses to the DefaultDirectory property and files/subdirectories below that. My hope is to prevent the user from selecting files that are on local drives or mapped drives not accessible to other users who will need the values stored in the database.

I think the way to do this is the TFileOpenDialog.OnFolderChanging event. But I’m not sure how to test if the selected file or folder is a child of DefaultDirectory. Given a filename or directory name, how can I tell if it is a dependent of DefaultDirectory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can compare the [`ShellItem`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Dialogs.TCustomFileDialog.ShellItem) property of the [`TFileOpenDialog`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Dialogs.TFileOpenDialog) dialog against the [`DefaultFolder`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Dialogs.TFileOpenDialog.DefaultFolder) property using the [`StartsText`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/StrUtils.StartsText) function and the set the `CanChange` value according to the result.

check this sample.

```
uses
 StrUtils,
 ActiveX,
 ShlObj;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm50.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FileOpenDialog1.DefaultFolder:='C:\Program Files';
  FileOpenDialog1.Execute;
end;

function GetItemName(Item: IShellItem; var ItemName: TFileName): HResult;
var
  pszItemName: LPCWSTR;
begin
  Result := Item.GetDisplayName(SIGDN_FILESYSPATH, pszItemName);
  if Failed(Result) then
    Result := Item.GetDisplayName(SIGDN_NORMALDISPLAY, pszItemName);
  if Succeeded(Result) then
  try
    ItemName := pszItemName;
  finally
    CoTaskMemFree(pszItemName);
  end;
end;


procedure TForm50.FileOpenDialog1FolderChanging(Sender: TObject;var CanChange: Boolean);
var
  CurrentDir : TFileName;
  Result     : HRESULT;
begin
  Result    := GetItemName(TFileOpenDialog(Sender).ShellItem,CurrentDir);
  CanChange := Succeeded(Result) and StartsText(TFileOpenDialog(Sender).DefaultFolder,CurrentDir);
  if not CanChange then
   ShowMessage('Sorry do you not have access to this folder');
end;
```

Comment: @daemon_x the `FileOpenDialog1.FileName` property not return the current directory inside of the `OnFolderChanging` which the user is trying to select. because that he must use the `ShellItem` property.

Comment: I've deleted my comment; but `FileOpenDialog1.FileName` actually returns displayed name (like Documents, Music etc.) of the item to be selected. You're right; it's necessary to use `GetDisplayName`, +1

Comment: Thanks for your help! And thank you for introducing me to StartsText. I've programmed Delphi for years and have never noticed that function. Would have come in handy in other projects.

Answer (score 0):

Just thinking along with what you're trying to do here...

You could always let the user choose a folder, and then show an error if an invalid path was chosen. After that, return the user to the root of the valid folder tree.

Advantages:

- You get to do your own validation. You could have multiple starting folders, or you can have more complex patterns in what you accept and what you don't.
- You can inform your users about what you want them to do, instead of forbidding what's not allowed. In modern UI patterns, it's adviced not to disable buttons, but to let the user click it, and then inform the user why a certain operation cannot be performed.  Otherwise it can be confusing for users why they cannot do certain things.

Comment: While you have good points, you're not addressing the question asked, which was "how do I tell if a folder is a sub-folder of another one?"